# Proof of work Algorithm for a simple blockchain implementation (F#)

Tags: f#, blockchain, sha256

I am currently trying to learn about blockchains and have understood the ground principles. So I am trying to implement a simple blockchain

The problem is that I cannot get a proof of work algorithm to function.

```
let sha256 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256.Create()
let hash (n : int) =
    sha256.ComputeHash (BitConverter.GetBytes n)
    |> BitConverter.ToString
    |> fun x -> x.Replace ("-", "")

let verify x = hash x |> fun p1 -> p1.EndsWith "0000"

let rec proofOfWork p0 x =
  if verify (p0 + x) then
     x
  else
     proofOfWork p0 (x + 1)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

   let s = proofOfWork 100 1
   let s' = proofOfWork s 1 
   let s'' = proofOfWork s' 1

   0
```

This returns a closed loop of "10312 -> 100 -> 10312" which seems to be fairly incorrect which makes sense if you think about it. So how would you actually go about creating one of these algorithms as I followed a guide in python which made an algorithm like this in exactly the same manner?

Comment: cannot figure out what's wrong here, could you please explain more details

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your proof of work algorithm. Your PoW algorithm should take some data X and find a number Y such that the hash of Y appended to X result in a number that in your case end with 4 trailing zeros.

A possible solution

```
let rec proofOfWork p0 x =
  let pow' = (string x) + (string p0) |> int
  if verify (pow') then
     x
  else
     proofOfWork p0 (x + 1)
```